# trouble instantiating an object and changing its layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, layer, gameobject

I tried it with the following steps;

1.- Take the GameObject I want to instantiate

```
public GameObject Arrow
```

2.- Take another GameObject as a reference to spawn it

```
public GameObject A
```

3.- Then, at some point in my code, instantiate it with that spawn GameObject coordinates and rotation

```
Instantiate (Arrow,  A.transform.position, A.transform.rotation);
```

4.- And finally changing the layer of the instantiated Gameobject to match the layer of the spawn Gameobject

```
Arrow.layer = A.layer;
```

I have the same script atacched to several gameobjects, the spawn point, which is public, it's interchangeable and I can choose between several of them that I have prepared all with diferent positions and layers.

The outcome of this is that all the instantiated objects spawn in the same point and have the wrong layer. they took 1 layer above instead, for example: one that should have got layer B has now layer A,
another that should have got layer C has now layer B.

Did I do something wrong, does what I've done do what I think it does?

Comment: some things look **very strange** - the variable "arrow" must be "arrow", not "Arrow".  you'd have to show your whole actual code, to get help!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a reference to the Instantiate GameObject you have to assign it to a variable, like this:

```
GameObject _oMyNewInstance = (GameObject) Instantiate (Arrow,  A.transform.position, A.transform.rotation);
```

So then you can use the variable to assign the layer and do other stuff:

```
_oMyNewInstance.layer = A.layer;
```

The statement `Arrow.layer = A.layer;`change the layer of the prefab/GameObject template (and that's why your obj B has A layer and obj C has B layer)